# Hovering over tags on Stack Overflow jobs should show the same info as other sites

Tags: feature-request, tags, stack-overflow-jobs

I got a job recommendation that had [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas).  I had never heard of this.  I clicked on the tag in the email, expecting to go to the tag wiki, but instead it took me a to a job search for only that tag.  Okay, I can live with that.  But from there I see absolutely no way to get to the tag wiki for that tag. Hovering doesn't do anything, and clicking of course performs a job filter.

Could we at least get the hover definition for tags on stackoverflow.com/jobs?

[image]

Comment: Interesting that this seems to be an issue for all jobs-related tags, for example job offers in the side bar, on the job offer site itself, and so on.